# NAT traversal requires STUN or TURN

Tags: docker, centos, webrtc, kurento, coturn

I'm a novice setting up a server for the first time to implement WebRTC
Linux is using Centos7 and has set up KMS and Coturn.
However, there is one problem.
The client and server are not connected on the screen, so I checked the logs of kms

## docker logs --follow kms

```
0:00:01.206579656     1 0x56191aac5010 INFO    KurentoServerMethods ServerMethods.cpp:90:ServerMethods: Using above 80% of system limits will throw NOT_ENOUGH_RESOURCES exception
0:00:01.206607827     1 0x56191aac5010 INFO    KurentoServerMethods ServerMethods.cpp:109:ServerMethods: System limits: unlimited threads, 32768 files
0:00:01.206902099     1 0x56191aac5010 INFO       KurentoWorkerPool WorkerPool.cpp:67:WorkerPool: Worker thread pool size: 2
0:00:01.207158442     1 0x56191aac5010 INFO    KurentoServerMethods ServerMethods.cpp:144:ServerMethods: RPC Request Cache is ENABLED
0:00:01.207351433     1 0x56191aac5010 INFO    KurentoWebSocketTransport WebSocketTransport.cpp:187:initWebSocket: WebSocket server (ws://) listening on address '::', port 8888
0:00:01.207411744     1 0x56191aac5010 INFO    KurentoWebSocketTransport WebSocketTransport.cpp:88:WebSocketTransport: Secure WebSocket server (wss://) not enabled
0:00:01.208078290     1 0x56191aac5010 INFO      KurentoMediaServer main.cpp:259:main: Kurento Media Server started
0:02:29.095818552     1 0x7f5070017630 INFO    KurentoWebRtcEndpointImpl WebRtcEndpointImpl.cpp:164:generateDefaultCertificates: Unable to load the RSA certificate from file. Using the default certificate.
0:02:29.284074137     1 0x7f5070017630 INFO    KurentoWebRtcEndpointImpl WebRtcEndpointImpl.cpp:174:generateDefaultCertificates: Unable to load the ECDSA certificate from file. Using the default certificate.
0:02:29.290405426     1 0x7f5070017630 INFO    KurentoWebRtcEndpointImpl WebRtcEndpointImpl.cpp:110:remove_not_supported_codecs_from_array:<kmswebrtcendpoint0> Removing not supported codec 'AMR/8000'
0:02:29.515589312     1 0x7f5064039e00 INFO         basertpendpoint kmsbasertpendpoint.c:1132:kms_base_rtp_endpoint_start_transport_send:<kmswebrtcendpoint0> Media 'video' has REMB
0:02:29.515721223     1 0x7f5064039e00 INFO         basertpendpoint kmsbasertpendpoint.c:1078:kms_base_rtp_endpoint_create_remb_manager:<kmswebrtcendpoint0> Creating REMB for session ID 0 (kmswebrtcendpoint0-sess0) and remote video SSRC 3653849939
0:02:29.515746113     1 0x7f5064039e00 INFO         basertpendpoint kmsbasertpendpoint.c:1089:kms_base_rtp_endpoint_create_remb_manager:<kmswebrtcendpoint0> REMB: Set RTCP min interval to 500 ms
0:02:29.519063004     1 0x7f5064007580 WARN        kmswebrtcsession kmswebrtcsession.c:823:kms_webrtc_session_set_stun_server_info:<kmswebrtcsession0> STUN server not configured! NAT traversal requires STUN or TURN
0:02:29.519107324     1 0x7f5064007580 WARN        kmswebrtcsession kmswebrtcsession.c:843:kms_webrtc_session_set_relay_info:<kmswebrtcsession0> TURN relay server not configured! NAT traversal requires STUN or TURN
0:02:29.522346434     1 0x7f50700054f0 INFO       KurentoWorkerPool WorkerPool.cpp:67:WorkerPool: Worker thread pool size: 2
0:02:40.930306053     1 0x7f5050001630 INFO    KurentoWebRtcEndpointImpl WebRtcEndpointImpl.cpp:110:remove_not_supported_codecs_from_array:<kmswebrtcendpoint1> Removing not supported codec 'AMR/8000'
0:02:40.951376487     1 0x7f5064018b30 INFO         basertpendpoint kmsbasertpendpoint.c:1132:kms_base_rtp_endpoint_start_transport_send:<kmswebrtcendpoint1> Media 'video' has REMB
0:02:40.951898082     1 0x7f5064018b30 INFO         basertpendpoint kmsbasertpendpoint.c:1078:kms_base_rtp_endpoint_create_remb_manager:<kmswebrtcendpoint1> Creating REMB for session ID 0 (kmswebrtcendpoint1-sess0) and remote video SSRC 3442416509
```

"NAT traversal requires STUN or TURN."

I don't know how to solve this part.

This is because the STUN server results from Trickle ICE were also successful.

[image]

If you know what I need to do, I'd appreciate it if you could tell me all the actions.

And please let me know if there is anything else I need to fill out!

Comment: You should look at the documentation of the system you're using for details on how to configure STUN and TURN. The logs are clearly stating they are not configured. If you provide references to the system others could also help you in finding that bit of information.

Answer (score 0):

### STUN and TURN

You dont have to have coturn if you are doing local testing. The warning is saying if you want to go outside of your network (out of your router and to the web) you will need a STUN or TURN server.

### Docker

Docker doesn't open the port 8888 by itself. You may need to open that port manually. To do this, add this `-p 8888:8888` when creating your container.

Or if you are using the Desktop version you can enter it into `Host port` under the `Optional settings` when you first run it.
[image]